# IOS how to pick image from camera roll in full resolution

Tags: ios, camera-roll

I am working on an IOS code to pick image from camera roll and upload to server, but the problem is that the image resolution of the picked image is according to the phone screen resolution and not the original image resolution. For example the resolution picked for Iphone-3 is always 320 x 320, but I want to load image in original resolution. Thanks

Comment: what does the code look like, where you are loading your image into your imageview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need this key in your dictionary: `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

So

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *fullImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

Comment: Just log the info dict. You will find a lot of helpful info there.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I have tried your code it does pick the image in original resolution but how do I crop it now? this was my original code.   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo

{

    [MyController saveImage:image resize:YES];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^

    {

        [[[App appDelegate] MyController] makeSearch];

    }];

}

Comment: Have a look at this question, it kind of answers any possible questions on `UIImagePickerController` and `UIImage`. Do you want the image cropped by the controllers UI?

Comment: Yes, I want to pick the image in original resolution and then apply cropping on it. With my code earlier it was doing the cropping but was not picking the original resolution, but with your code it is now picking the image in original resolution but not cropping. I must be missing some little thing but please excuse me for that because i am new to IOS. Can you please clarify? Thanks